# Using custom fonts in Swing application

Tags: configuration, fonts, java

I have two specific fonts installed on my computer and would like to configure the JRE to make them
available to my application, specifically `Calibri` and `Cambria Math`.  However, I understand the basics of how default fonts work in Java; how the JRE reads a properties file that sets the default fonts for any Java application running on top of it.

**However**, these two fonts are not available in any of the properties files that I can find. So:

(1) Is it possible to "add" these two new fonts to the JRE's config, so that in my program I can call `myJButton.setFont(myCambriaMathFont)` on a component and make use of these added fonts? If so, how? If not, then:

(2) Are there any libraries/JARs out there for matching font names/font families to the fonts available via the JRE, and matching them as close as possible, algorithmically?

C'mon, I know you'd all love to see what a JList looks like....*on Wingdings*!!!

Thanks and sorry for this quirky question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would you like to load the font at runtime?
See [Font.createFont(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont(int,%20java.io.File))